# Create a simple dynamic library

Tags: c, gcc

What linking step am I missing? I'm trying to make a dynamic library from file `c.c`:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int my_function(void)
{
  return a() + EIGHT;
}
```

which depends on `a.c`:

```
int a(void)
{
  return 1;
}
```

and `b.h`:

```
enum {
  EIGHT = 8,
};
```

I run `gcc -c c.c -o c.o` to compile the object file. Then I run

```
gcc -Wall -dynamiclib -o libc.dylib c.c
```

and I get this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_a", referenced from:
      _b in ccx5LSkL.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I properly link the files? References addressing this specific problem would be awesome.

Comment: `gcc -PIC -c c.c -o c.o`

Comment: I get `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-PIC'`

Comment: Sorry. That should've been `-fPIC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your first line, `gcc -c c.c -o c.o`, compiled the object file `c.o`. Now you then have to use `c.o` for creating the final result. So your linking step should be using `c.o`, not `c.c`.

Next, the error you are getting is that the symbol `"_a"` was not found. This is coming from you calling the function `a()`, but not including it in the linking step. To do that you need to also compile `a.c` and include it when linking your final product.

So in total, your process should be:

1) compile:

```
gcc -c a.c -o a.o
gcc -c c.c -o c.o
```

2) link:

```
gcc -Wall -dynamiclib -o libc.dylib a.o c.o
```

Note that to compile `libc.dylib`, you had to include all the sources that the final result would depend on.

Finally, you don't actually need to compile all of the object files separately. You can compile and link together in one combined step by just providing the `*.c` files right away.

```
gcc -Wall -dynamiclib -o libc.dylib a.c c.c
```

So your problem was really just about not including both sources together. (Other than `-dynamiclib`, everything actually works basically just like compiling a regular executable.)

Comment: Thanks! There is no `b.c`. Only `b.h`.

Comment: Just caught that, too! :) no problem.